# How can I connect openvpn to a specific port?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, split-tunnel, split-tunneling

I want to use openvpn. But with some differences.
I don’t want to send all trafics to the vpn. For example, when using FoxyProxy on firefox and connected to localhost:8000, send traffics to vpn but when the FoxyProxy is off, send traffic to the regular ports (and not connected to the VPN)
How can I do that? Maybe with vpn split tunneling or something else?
I’m using linux as the openvpn client

Comment: Split tunneling is a routing (L3) concept while the ports operate on transport layer (L4). Therefore, there's no port based split tunneling. This might be possible using some firewall rules, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this in foxyproxy with the built-in whitelist/blacklist.

Set foxyproxy config to "Use enabled proxies by patterns and order" and add a pattern for "all URL's", type: wildcard. This will be your default.

Then add a new black pattern with the hostname you don't want to use the proxy for (I think localhost/127.0.0.1 etc are already in it) when you create it.

Good luck!